# Android : Alert Dialog validation proper way

Tags: android

We can perform a validation by adding a positive button with implementation

```
final EditText urlEditText = new EditText(this);

DialogInterface.OnClickListener event = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                try
                {
                    // Validate URL
                    new URL(urlEditText.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "URL Accepted", 1).show();
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid URL", 1).show();
                }
            }
        };

AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Enter the server URL here")
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",event)
                    .setView(urlEditText)
                    .create();
        dialog.show();
```

If we enter a wrong URL it will be validated and display a wrong URL `Toast`. However, the dialog is dismissed it should be still displayed until the user press "Cancel" or enter the correct URL. There are solutions around here like recreating the dialog and display it to user again but this would be a good idea.

Is there a way that If we enter a wrong URL the `AlertDialog` still there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `AlertDialog.getButton()` so we can get button reference of `AlertDialog`. This should be called if the dialog is shown to user.

```
final EditText urlEditText = new EditText(this);


final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Enter the server URL here")
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",null)
                    .setView(urlEditText)
                    .create();
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {

                Button okButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        try
                        {
                            new URL(urlEditText.getText().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "URL Accepted", 1).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid URL", 1).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE 1:** We can use `AlertDialog.BUTTON1` but it is now deprecated.

Comment: nice work ..God Bless

Answer (score 1):

`URLUtil` provides useful methods like

```
isHttpUrl();
isValidUrl();
```

try to use one of them to validate your URL entered in `EditText`. And if `URL` is not valid, display alert one more time or don't `dismiss` dialog.